# Como validar un campo de un Google Form con Expresiones Regulares

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-forms

Hola pretendo validar respuestas de un Google Form mediante expresiones regulares, pero no funciona correctamente.

He intentado lo siguiente:

```
  const nif=formulari.addTextItem();
  var validacioNIF = FormApp.createTextValidation()
    .setHelpText('Ex.NIF: 12345678Z, Ex.NIE: Y1234567X.')
    .requireTextContainsPattern("/^[0-9]{8}[A-Z]|[LMXYZ][0-9]{7}[A-Z]$/i")
    .build(); 
  
  nif.setTitle("NIF:")
  .setHelpText("Introduïu el vostre NIF sense cap separacio. Ex.:12345678A")
  .setRequired(true);
  nif.setValidation(validacioNIF);

  const correu=formulari.addTextItem();
  var validacioCorreu = FormApp.createTextValidation()
  .requireTextIsEmail()
  .setHelpText('Introduix una addreça de correu vàlida Ex.: usuari@sevidor.dom.')
  //
  .build();
  correu.setTitle("Correu electrònic:")
  .setRequired(true);
  correu.setValidation(validacioCorreu);

  const telefon=formulari.addTextItem();
  var validacioTelefon = FormApp.createTextValidation()
    .setHelpText('Introduïu el vostre telèfon de contacte Ex.:666444301.')
    .requireTextContainsPattern("/^[6-9][0-9]{8}$/i")
  .build(); 
  telefon.setTitle("Telèfon:")
  .setHelpText("Introduïu el telèfon sense cap separacio. Ex.:61234567")
  .setRequired(true);
  telefon.setValidation(validacioTelefon);

  var data=[],pregSes=[];
  var dia,torn;
  var nSes=0;
  const ckboxSesions=formulari.addGridItem();
  ckboxSesions.setRequired(true)
  .setTitle("Sessions previstes:");
  ckboxSesions.setColumns(["Puc assistir.", "No podré assistir."]);
```

El resultado es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me indica que todo es incorrecto.
Alguien me puede ayudar a resolver el problema?
Gràcies.

Comment: ¿Has revisado que la expresión regular se haya pasado correctamente al formulario? Agrega varios ejemplos de valores válidos e inválidos.

Answer (score 0):

Vale ya lo he encontrado, y es tan simple que me da hasta vergüenza.

El tema esta en que la expresion regular hay que ponerla sin los carácteres de principio y fin de la expresión.

```
.requireTextContainsPattern("[0-9]{8}[A-Za-z]|[LMXYZlmxyz][0-9]{7}[A-Za-z]")
```

Al no poder/saber indicar la (i)nsensitive hay que repetir los grupos de letras tanto en maúsculas como en minusculas si queremos que acepte ambas.

Gràcies [Ruben](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/65/rub%c3%a9n) y a todos.

Comment: Añado un comentario de corrección sobre mi solucion. La funcion utilizada (.requireTextContainsPattern()) indica que la respuesta debe contener texto que se ajuste al patrón RegEx, Si se introduce un valor como A12345678B, lo daria como correcto porque 12345678B cumple con el patrón. Pero en un caso como el mio necesito que la respuesta completa se ajuste al patrón por lo que he de utilizar la función **.requireTextMatchesPattern()**  de esta manera una respuesta como A12345678B seria incorrecta.